# Matlab: Chi-squared fit (chi2gof) to test if data is exponentially distributed

Tags: matlab, statistics, goodness-of-fit, exponential-distribution

I guess this is a simple question, but I can't sort it out. I have a vector, the first elements of which look like:

```
V = [31 52 38 29 29 34 29 24 25 25 32 28 24 28 29 ...];
```

and I want to perform a `chi2gof` test in Matlab to test if `V` is exponentially distributed. I did:

```
[h,p] = chi2gof(V,'cdf',@expcdf);
```

but I get a warning message saying:

```
Warning: After pooling, some bins still have low expected counts.
The chi-square approximation may not be accurate
```

Have I defined the `chi2gof` call incorrectly?

Comment: Just a guess: maybe the data vector is too small

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that's a sample. The original is 36 elements. It should be ok...thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At 36 values, you have a very small sample set. From the second sentence of Wikipedia's article on the [chi-squared test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson's_chi-squared_test) (emphasis added):

> It is suitable for unpaired data from *large samples*.

Large in this case usually means around at least 100. Read about more [assumptions of this test here](http://www.basic.northwestern.edu/statguidefiles/gf-dist_ass_viol.html).

**Alternatives**

You might try [`kstest`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kstest.html) in Matlab, which is based on the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov-Smirnov_test):

```
[h,p] = kstest(V,'cdf',[V(:) expcdf(V(:),expfit(V))])
```

Or try [`lillietest`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lillietest.html), which is based on the [Lilliefors test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilliefors_test) and has an option specifically for exponential distributed data:

```
[h,p] = lillietest(V,'Distribution','exp')
```

In case you can increase your sample size, you are doing one thing wrong with [`chi2gof`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/chi2gof.html). From the `help` for the `'cdf'` option:

> A fully specified cumulative distribution function.  This
>                     can be a ProbabilityDistribution object, a function
>                     handle, or a function. name.  The function must take X
>                     values as its only argument. Alternately, you may provide
>                     a cell array whose first element is a function name or
>                     handle, and whose later elements are parameter values,
>                     one per cell. The function must take X values as its
>                     first argument, and other parameters as later arguments.

You're not supplying any additional parameters, so [`expcdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/expcdf.html) is using the default mean parameter of `mu = 1`. Your data values are very large and don't correspond at all an [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) with this mean. You need to estimate parameters as well. You the [`expfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/expfit.html) function, which is basted on [maximum likelihood expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood), you might try something like this:

```
[h,p] = chi2gof(V,'cdf',@(x)expcdf(x,expfit(x)),'nparams',1)
```

However, with only 36 samples you may not get a very good estimate for a distribution like this and still may not get expected results even for data sampled from a known distribution, e.g.:

```
V = exprnd(10,1,36);
[h,p] = chi2gof(V,'cdf',@(x)expcdf(x,expfit(x)),'nparams',1)
```

Comment: Fantastic explanation. Thanks so much. Could you please suggest additional literature for backing up that a large sample for Chi2 is about 100?

Comment: Moreover, what if the lilliefors accepts the null hypothesis, and KS rejects it? It seems that this is happening to me, unless I made a mistake in the commands.

Comment: That is a well-know property of the chi-squared test and will be found in any good text. 100 is a rule of thumb. The point is that you need lots of them for the test to work well and you need a few in each bin/cell the test divides them into. I've updated my answer with an additional resource. Keep in mind that StackOverflow is geared toward programming; not Math/Statistics, per se. If you have a question about which test to use in which situation, it would probably be better-suited for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) or [Math.StackExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com).